# Postgress Serialisation Error For SKIP Locked with repeatable read

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, jdbc, locked

I am running a query with skip locked

```
select * from booker.review_tasks where review_task_id in (
    2140285001,
2140285031,
2140304551
    ) for update skip locked ;
```

And then updating it using another concurrent transaction

```
update booker.review_tasks set priority = 190 where review_task_id  in (2140285001,
2140304551);
```

I am getting an error in the first transaction as

```
was aborted: ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.

    at com.amazon.contentreviewplatformservice.db.RWNamedJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(RWNamedJdbcTemplate.java:126) ~[ContentReviewPlatformService-1.0.jar:?]

    at com.amazon.contentreviewplatformservice.db.dao.DAOUtils.changeUserTaskAssignmentStatus(DAOUtils.java:126) ~[ContentReviewPlatformService-1.0.jar:?]

    at com.amazon.contentreviewplatformservice.workflow.dao.WorkflowManagerDAO.changeReviewState(WorkflowManagerDAO.java:784) ~[ContentReviewPlatformService-1.0.jar:?]
```

How can a row be updating when its locked , or if locked is skip why is there error of concurrent update

Comment: have you tried in one transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` first selects the rows and then locks them. It sees the database in the state of its transaction snapshot, which was taken by the first statement in the `REPEATABLE READ` transaction, possibly a while back.

After the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` has found a row, it will try to lock it. Now if the `UPDATE` has run at any time between the time the snapshot was taken and the attempt to lock the row, PostgreSQL determines that the row version it would have to lock is different from the row version the transaction sees and throws a serialization error.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Laurenz Albe. Is there any way I can reproduce this in Local/IDE. I tired reproducing it in DataGrip opening two different console and running query , but was unable to reproduce it. Now the way you explained. It might be that I have to run update query when the select for update skip locked is running but I am not able to add a delay between select for update and skip locked.

Comment: Sure. Start a repeatable read transaction and run some random query. Then run the `UPDATE` in a second session. Then run the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` in the first session.